# Rmarkdown inline code renders Unicode instead of UTF-8

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, r-markdown, knitr

I know it has been adressed several times, but despite many investigations and tries, I have been unabled to solve it so far.
Basically, Rmarkdown fails to render cyrillic characters where there are evaluated in inline code:

```r
---
title: "My Title"
output: html_document
---

### Заказчик

### `r "Заказчик"`

### `r knitr::asis_output("Заказчик")`
```

produces

[image]

My session info is :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.1.0  fastmap_1.1.0   htmltools_0.5.2 tools_4.1.0     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.11  knitr_1.34      xfun_0.26      
 [9] digest_0.6.28   rlang_0.4.11    evaluate_0.14
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: UTF-8 is Unicode (one of the official encoding). In your environment, you have `French_France.1252`, and so markdown try to enforce your encoding (CP1252, so not UTF-8). If you want UTF-8, set it in your locale

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi how would you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works nice.

For the future, create a Rmd-file in the utf-8 encoding.

If you forgot to do that - use "file - > reopen with encoding".

Also, you can use `enc2utf8`

```
### Заказчик

### `r enc2utf8("Заказчик")`

### `r knitr::asis_output("Заказчик")`
```

[image]

My session info:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 1251

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.4.0     ggplot2_3.3.5     dplyr_1.0.7       kableExtra_1.3.4 
[5] formattable_0.2.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. Could you share your sessionInfo() as well ?

Comment: @Jrm_FRL Look, but I don't know, how it help you.